# underscore finding nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js

I'm trying to use underscore to find an object in the array which has a child with a certain condition. lets say this is my array:

```
"array": [
  {
     "user": {
        "profileIcon": 913,
        "id": 62019870
     },
     "count": 1
  },
  {
     "user": {
        "profileIcon": 770,
        "id": 32558522
     },
     "count": 2
  }
]
```

Now I want to only return an object that has user.id : 62019870. 
This is the code I have so far but it returns an empty array:

```
 var arr = _.filter(array, function(obj) {
                return _.findWhere(obj.user, {id: 62019870});
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findWhere` function works on the array, not on the object. For your case, you can simply do

```
console.log(_.filter(array, function(obj) {
  return obj.user.id === 62019870;
}));
// [ { user: { profileIcon: 913, id: 62019870 }, count: 1 } ]
```

---

If your environment supports, native `Array.prototype.filter` then you can do the same without underscore, like this

```
array.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.user.id === 62019870;
});
```

---

If your environment supports [ECMA Script 2015's Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), then you can write the same, more succinctly, like this

```
array.filter(obj => obj.user.id === 62019870);
```

Comment: I will prefer @alexreardon way, if I don't need to worry about IE8 it's `native` filter .

Comment: @alexreardon Thanks, included that suggestion also in the answer.